# What do you look for in a dependency to determine if it should be an injected dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am having difficult figuring out when a dependency should be injected. Let's just work with a simple example from my project:

```
class CompanyDetailProvider : ICompanyDetailProvider {
    private readonly FilePathProvider provider;
    public CompanyDetailProvider(FilePathProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CompanyDetail> GetCompanyDetailsForDate(DateTime date) {
        string path = this.provider.GetCompanyDetailFilePathForDate(date);
        var factory = new DataReaderFactory();
        Func<IDataReader> sourceProvider = () => factory.CreateReader(
            DataFileType.FlatFile, 
            path
        );
        var hydrator = new Hydrator<CompanyDetail>(sourceProvider);
        return hydrator;
    }
}
```

(Not production quality!)

`ICompanyDetailProvider` is responsible for providing instances of `CompanyDetail`s for consumers. The concrete implementation `CompanyDetailProvider` does it by hydrating instances of `CompanyDetail` from a file using a `Hydrator<T>` which uses reflection to populate instances of `T` sourced from an `IDataReader`. Clearly `CompanyDetailProvider` is dependent on `DataReaderFactory` (which returns instances of `OleDbDataReader` given a path to a file) and `Hydrator`. Should these dependencies be injected? Is it right to inject `FilePathProvider`? What qualities do I examine to decide if they should be injected?

Answer (score 2):

I evaluate dependencies' points of use through the intent/mechanism lens: is this code clearly communicating its intent, or do I have to extract that from a pile of implementation details?

If the code indeed looks like a pile of implementation details, I determine the inputs and outputs and create an entirely new dependency to represent the *why* behind all the *how*. I then push the complexity into the new dependency, making the original code simpler and clearer.

When I read the code in this question, I clearly see the retrieval of a file path based on a date, followed by an opaque set of statements which don't clearly communicate the goal of reading an entity of a certain type at a certain path. I can work my way through it but that breaks my stride.

I suggest you raise the level of abstraction of the second half of the calculation, after you get the path. I would start by defining a dependency which implements the code's inputs/outputs:

```
public interface IEntityReader
{
    IEnumerable<T> ReadEntities<T>(string path);
}
```

Then, rewrite the original class using this intention-revealing interface:

```
public sealed class CompanyDetailProvider : ICompanyDetailProvider
{
    private readonly IFilePathProvider _filePathProvider;
    private readonly IEntityReader _entityReader;

    public CompanyDetailProvider(IFilePathProvider filePathProvider, IEntityReader entityReader)
    {
        _filePathProvider = filePathProvider;
        _entityReader = entityReader;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CompanyDetail> GetCompanyDetailsForDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var path = _filePathProvider.GetCompanyDetailsFilePathForDate(date);

        return _entityReader.ReadEntities<CompanyDetail>(path);
    }
}
```

Now you can sandbox the gory details, which become quite cohesive in isolation:

```
public sealed class EntityReader : IEntityReader
{
    private readonly IDataReaderFactory _dataReaderFactory;

    public EntityReader(IDataReaderFactory dataReaderFactory)
    {
        _dataReaderFactory = dataReaderFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadEntities<T>(string path)
    {
        Func<IDataReader> sourceProvider =
            () => _dataReaderFactory.CreateReader(DataFileType.FlatFile, path);

        return new Hydrator<T>(sourceProvider);
    }
}
```

As shown in this example, I think you should abstract the data reader factory away and directly instantiate the hydrator. The distinction is that `EntityReader` *uses* the data reader factory, while it only *creates* the hydrator. It isn't actually dependent on the instance at all; instead, it serves as a hydrator factory.

Answer (score 1):

### How to determine if a class should use dependency injection

---

Does this class require an external dependency?

If yes, inject.

If no, has no dependency.

To answer "Is it right to inject FilePathProvider?" yes it is right.

**Edit:** For clarification any external dependency is where you call to an unrelated but dependent class, *especially* when it involves a physical resources such as reading File Pathes from disk, but this also implies any kind of service or model class that does logic indepedent to the core functionality of the class.

Generally this be surmised with anytime you call the new operator. In most circumstances you want to refactor away all usages of the new operator when it has to deal with any class other than a data transfer object. When the class is internal to the usage location then a new statement can be fine if it reduces complexity such as the new DataReaderFactory() however this does appear to be a very good candidate for constructor injection also.

Comment: What do you mean "external dependency"? What meaning does the modifier "external" give to "dependency"?

Comment: An depedency to an external resource, such as a database, file system, web service, system clock.

Comment: @Steven: That can't possibly be right lest Chris Marisic means we only inject dependencies that have dependencies on external resources which seems far too restrictive; there are clearly dependencies that don't have dependencies on external resources that should be injected.

Comment: @Crazy: I have only one rule for injecting dependencies, when it makes unit testing easier. If you abstract too much away you have a change of testing not enough or the wrong stuff. Invert the dependencies when a dependency makes testing harder, because it goes to the file system for instance, or the database. In that sense, it could be logical to replace the dependency on `DataReaderFactory`, and not on `FilePathProvider`, since the only thing it does is returning a string.

Comment: I agree with @Steven. Anything that makes unit testing easier is an injectible candidate. It doesn't have to be just external interfaces, but anything that makes testing more isolated is a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to be on the more liberal side of injecting dependencies so I would definitely want to inject both IDataReader to get rid of the new DataFactoryReader and the Hydrator. It keeps everything more loosely coupled which of course makes it easier to maintain.

Another benefit that is easy to attain right away is better testability. You can create mocks of your IDataReader and Hydrator to isolate your unit tests to just the GetCompanyDetailsForDate method and not have to worry about what happens inside the datareader and hydrator.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, but I don't understand what you mean by "I would definitely want to inject both `IDataReader` to get rid of the new `DataFactoryReader` and the `Hydrator`." I would still need to use `Hydrator` to populate instances of `CompanyDetail` from the `IDataReader` and thus I would have to `new` one up or have a `HydratorFactory` injected.

Comment: right, that's what i intended to say. i would inject both the IDataReader and HydratorFactory. sorry for the confusion.